# Selenium>Webdriver>Java>When clicking on button in a model window, another background button is triggering

Tags: java, selenium, model, webdriver

On my checkout page, for a 3rd party payment provider, in a model window I am able to locate my desired button with my xpath & only one button is showing up. However when my automation script is running, it is click another button which is not in the model window but in the same position as my desired button but in the background of my model window.Any advise.

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. At the moment no one knows how the html structure of element looks like, Do Not Add Picture of it No one will write that for you.Also what are your trials and errors?

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you added the code to switch to this model window before clicking on the button?


 public void waitForNewWindowAndSwitchToIt(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
                String cHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();           
                String newWindowHandle = null;
                Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

                //Wait for 20 seconds for the new window and throw exception if not found
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    if (allWindowHandles.size() > 1) {
                        for (String allHandlers : allWindowHandles) {
                            if (!allHandlers.equals(cHandle))
                                newWindowHandle = allHandlers;                          
                        }
                        driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
                if (cHandle == newWindowHandle) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Time out - No window found");
                }
            }
```